# Renew SSL Certificate inside Keycloak Docker Container - still using old certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, jboss, keycloak, mounted-volumes

I setup a keycloak container from this manual:
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

I used the following command:

```
docker run -d --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -p 8443:8443 -e 
KEYCLOAK_USER=******* -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=******** 
--mount type=bind,source=/home/cert/keycloak.key,target=/etc/x509/https/tls.key 
--mount type=bind,source=/home/cert/keycloak.crt,target=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt 
jboss/keycloak
```

It worked like a charm until the SSL run outdated.
The files are located inside the container under the following path:
etc/x509/https

I thought it would be possible updating the SSL-Certificates just by copying them over

**UPDATE:**
The tls files are bind to Volumes:

```
"Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/cert/keycloak.key",
            "Destination": "/etc/x509/https/tls.key",
```

I copied the files to the folder /home/cert and replaced the original ones. After that i restarted the container but when accessing the homepage it still shows the "old" outdated cert.

**UPDATE2:**
I also run the recommended script:

```
sudo docker exec -it keycloak /bin/bash
cd /opt/jboss/tools/
bash x509.sh
```

Which returned

```
Creating HTTPS keystore via OpenShift's service serving x509 certificate secrets..
HTTPS keystore successfully created at: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keystores/https-keystore.jks
```

After that I restarted the container and still using the old certificates....

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. I am also stuck renewing the certificates. The `x509.sh` script is designed to run only once during the start. I had to do a docker-compose down and up for the container to pickup the new certificates.

Comment: I am pretty new to docker, could you post the commands you used?

Comment: Yes, sure, but before suggesting commands, I need to understand your setup. can you update your answer with the exact command you are using to spin up the container?